# OpenTTD Loading & Unloading times

Tags: openttd

I'm trying to calculate **the time for a train to load at a station**.

[This website](https://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?t=59761)
states that a full load and unload cycle takes `(capacity * 2 / load_amount)` days

So a full load would be `(capacity / load_amount)`

It also states that a **"load amount"** is loaded in these times:

- **Trains: 40 ticks**
- RV: 20 ticks
- Ships: 10 ticks
- Aircraft: 20 ticks

Using these formulas, for a monorail train with 108 passenger carriages **(5076 passengers)** and 10 mail carriages **(370 bags of mail)**, it would take `5446/40 days = 136 days`.

*(Note: The train is on a station length 64, and the train is length 60)*

However, the train actually only takes around **10 days** to fully load, very different to the calculated value.

So my overall question: **What is the correct formula to use to calculate load times?**

Comment: I would very much appreciate any ideas that might lead to a solution, even if they're not a full answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mis-interpreting "load amount".

`load_amount` is an internal attribute of a wagon or vehicle that determines how big a chunk of cargo is loaded during each cycle.  For example, a train wagon with a `load_amount` of 16 will load 16 units of cargo every 40 ticks.  If the wagon has a capacity of 40 units, it'll take 100 ticks to fully load.

If a train fully fits into a station, each wagon will load independently, so the total loading time will be the loading time of the slowest wagon in the train.